# Oracle OCI get id of last inserted row

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I´m writing a C++ code that in some point needs to get the ID of the last inserted row.

Based on [this link here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/289245?start=0&tstart=0) I made up this code, but it is returning only trash (invalid characters):

```
    std::string sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (FIELD_A, FIELD_B) VALUES (10, 20)";

    OCIStmt *stmthp;
    int sts = OCIHandleAlloc( (dvoid *) envhp, (dvoid **) &stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);
    CheckOracleError(sts);

    sts = OCIStmtPrepare(stmthp, errhp, (const OraText *) sql.c_str(), (ub4) sql.size(), (ub4) OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT);
    CheckOracleError(sts);

    sts = OCIStmtExecute(svchp, stmthp, errhp, (ub4) 1, (ub4) 0, (CONST OCISnapshot *) NULL, (OCISnapshot *) NULL, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

    if (sts != OCI_NO_DATA && sts != OCI_SUCCESS)
        CheckOracleError(sts);


    OraText rowID[19]; // Extra char for null termination.
    ub2 size = 18;
    OCIRowid *pRowID;
    std::memset(rowID, 0, 19); // Set to all nulls so that string will be null terminated.
    OCIDescriptorAlloc(envhp, (void**)&pRowID, OCI_DTYPE_ROWID, 0, NULL);
    OCIAttrGet(stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, pRowID, 0, OCI_ATTR_ROWID, errhp);
    OCIRowidToChar(pRowID, rowID, &size, errhp);

    OCIHandleFree(stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT);
```

Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Comment: `ROWID` is a [pseudocolumn generated by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) and is **NOT** a primary key for the table as it can be changed if the data is deleted and re-entered or if you have row movement enabled. You should have a primary key for your table preferably generated by a sequence or, in 12c, an identity column.

Comment: Hummm. I got it.... Actually **I DO HAVE** a primary key called *ID* that is generated by a sequence. I need to get this `ID` from the last inserted row, not the `ROWID`.... How should I do them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  ID      INT PRIMARY KEY,
  FIELD_A INT,
  FIELD_B INT
);
```

You can create a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mytable__id__seq;
```

Then you can do all the inserts via a procedure (and can use a package to group all the create/read/update/delete functionality together into one place) then you can use `RETURNING .. INTO ..` within the package and get the value from an out variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mytable_pkg
AS
  PROCEDURE add(
    i_field_a IN  MYTABLE.FIELD_A%TYPE,
    i_field_b IN  MYTABLE.FIELD_B%TYPE,
    o_id      OUT MYTABLE.ID%TYPE
  );

  -- PROCEDURE edit( ... );
  -- PROCEDURE del( ... );
END mytable_pkg;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mytable_pkg
AS
  PROCEDURE add(
    i_field_a IN  MYTABLE.FIELD_A%TYPE,
    i_field_b IN  MYTABLE.FIELD_B%TYPE,
    o_id      OUT MYTABLE.ID%TYPE
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable (
      id,
      field_a,
      field_b
    ) VALUES (
      mytable__id__seq.NEXTVAL,
      i_field_a,
      i_field_b
    )
    RETURNING id INTO o_id;
  END add;

  -- PROCEDURE edit( ... );
  -- PROCEDURE del( ... );
END mytable_pkg;
/
```

Then you can call the stored procedure using OCI and just use the bound value from the out parameter. There are plenty of examples (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/591467/1509264) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25770846/1509264)) that you can refer to.

Comment: When/how do you plan to use this ID. Keep in mind that any value used for a PK (or anything else) is (1) not visible to other sessions until COMMITed, and (2) subject to being lost forever if the inserting transaction is rolled back.